# Get html of current page store that html and use it later

Tags: javascript, html

I am create a tool where users can create their social share bar, but now I would like to create an in text styling feature so they set this piece of html in text to render the social share buttons:

```
<div id="fs_social-bar-wrapper"></div>
```

Than I have a function determine html which look like this:

```
function determineHtml(){
  var socialWrapper = document.querySelector(".socialShare").outerHTML;
  var shareBarStyling = localStorage.getItem("shareBarStyling");

  if(shareBarStyling === "floating_bar" || shareBarStyling === "expanding_bar"){
    document.querySelector("#shareButton-code").innerHTML += socialWrapper;
  } else if(shareBarStyling === "inline_bar"){
    document.querySelector("#shareButton-code").innerHTML += `<div id="fs_social-bar-wrapper"></div>`;
  }
}
```

This is all good and renders the social bar wrapper div but how can I later append the 
  `var socialWrapper = document.querySelector(".socialShare").outerHTML;` to the wrapper.

So basically when the user finishes the creation they get a piece of code and here is the function which needs to append the current html later on.

```
function appendInlineHtml(){
  document.querySelector("#fs_social-bar-wrapper").innerHTML = document.querySelector(".socialShare").outerHTML;
}
```

FYI: the output needs to work stand alone, ofcourse the above is not working because the selector `.socialShare` is not available in other documents.

So how can I store the current html of `document.querySelector(".socialShare")` to render this later on in a stand alone document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: Why don't you just make two. three different HTML templates the user can embed? I don't understand why you'd want to use localStorage and a script just to create different versions, while you can just create different snippets of HTML to begin with.

Comment: @Shilly because this html template is dynamic based on the users choice

Comment: I understand that, but will the user change their choices After they have created the code in your tool? And if so, why not opt for CSS styling so a floating bar can become an expanding bar without javascript involved?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery,

```
var html = $("html").html();
```

If want to use pure JavaScript,

```
var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

You can `html` use it later.

Comment: lets say I use this and load this in an other file than it will store the current html of that new file.

Comment: Can you explain me how are you loading this another file ?

Comment: First I let the user click through a menu and choose some options. Than they click a button and it will render <style>html and the script. They will copy this code into a new file thats why it needs to be stand alone